# How to check <br /> in testarea with php

Tags: php

In my comment area i have problem about

suppose a user enter:

```
hello
how are you?
```

out put is:

```
hello how are you?
```

And i want it as user enter:

```
hello
how are you?
```

I am using `HTMLPurifier` and `tidy` lib but noting helps out

Is there a inbuild function in php to do this?

Comment: Use [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function.

Comment: A line break doesn't mean anything in HTML!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You [nl2tobr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) php function it changes new line characters to `<br>` tag

The `<br>` tag inserts a single line break.

[nl2tobr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)  takes two arguments. First is string where newline characters will be replaced, and second one tell function to replace it either to `<br>` or to `<br />`(XHTML)

**Example from manual**:

```
<?php
 echo nl2br("Welcome\r\nThis is my HTML document", false);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
 Welcome<br>
 This is my HTML document
```

By default the second argument is set to **TRUE**

Comment: **, false);** adding false is needed?

Comment: It is not needed I've wrote in last sentence that default argument is TRUE so when you write "false" newline will be changed to `<BR>` but when you put **TRUE** or nothing it will be changed to `<BR />` as xhtml standard says.

Comment: Ok thanks Robert :) its done on my site and working fine :)

Answer (score 3):

I thinnk you can use [**`nl2br`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to achieve this

example from manual

```
echo nl2br("foo isn't\n bar");
```

output

```
foo isn't<br />
bar
```

This will change new line into `<br>` tag which will handle line breaks

Answer (score 2):

you have to use the php function

```
nl2br($textAreaInput)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the function nl2br:

```
echo nl2br($textareaMessage);
```

Answer (score 1):

use nl2br() function, pass the TextArea String to nl2br() function, textarea added "\n\r" for line break but for html we need to convert it to 
 for linen break, which nl2br() do.

Comment: not only `\n\r` it also changes `\r\n`, `\n` and `\r`